# creating a linear fit using the lm() method

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I'm wondering how to create a fit on this scatterplot. below is a scatterplot
created with this code

```
Human <- ggplot(starwars_Human) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = height, y = mass), position = "jitter") 
Human
```

[image]

I'm thinking that this is how you add a linear fit using the lm() method, but it doesn't seem to work

```
geom_smooth(method='lm', formula= height~mass)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to specify the formula. It is inherited from arguments `x` and `y` in the `aes` function.

Try:

```
Human <- ggplot(starwars_Human, aes(x = height, y = mass)) + 
  geom_point(position = "jitter") +
  geom_smooth(method = lm)
Human
```